# When to use async in map for Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Consider the following code:

```
async function deleteFile(file) { ... }

function run() {
   await Promise.all(files.map(async file => deleteFile(file)));
}
```

1) Is it correct that `async` before `file` is unnecessary, because `deleteFile` already returns a Promise, i.e. is already `async`?

2) Does that means that `async` would only be needed if for example an anonymous function in `map` was synchronous? Like so:

```
function run() {
   await Promise.all(files.map(async file => { return "file"; }));
}
```

Comment: correct - if `deleteFile` returns a promise, no need to use `async` for the `.map`  callback - if `deleteFile` doesn't return a promise, then the code won't work as you expect - of course, without seeing the content of `deleteFile` there's no guarantee this will work, it depends very much on the code in that function

Comment: *That means that async would only be needed if for example an anonymous function in map was synchronous* - no ... because Promise.all can work with non-promises, so no need to use async in this case either

Comment: @JaromandaX Then why does this answer (and the other answers too) use `async item` if it just returns an Integer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56103352/1870795

Comment: Because not everyone truly grasps Promises, and Promise.all (and I don't claim to know **everything** either) - try with/without the async to see there's no difference with the **result**  *in this case*

Comment: And I thought my question here would be downvoted because it was too easy. Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @JaromandaX If you want to add this as answer I will accept it.